# Помогите с запятой 14

Tags: пунктуация

Не могу понять, почему здесь ставится запятая. Объясните, пожалуйста.

**В 90% случаях, я не показываю мои настоящие эмоции.**

Answer (score 3):

В 90% случа**ев** (управление Р.п.) я не показываю мои настоящие эмоции.

**Здесь не должно быть запятой, нет причин для обособления**. Обстоятельство не обособляется, входит в основное сообщение и относится ко всему предложению (распространяет его грамматическую основу), такое обстоятельство называется **детерминантом**.

После обстоятельства делается **произносительная пауза**, но она не должна обозначаться запятой, так как не связана с грамматикой.

**Сравнить:** Я, в 90% случаях, не показываю мои настоящие эмоции.

Здесь, в позиции между подлежащим и сказуемым,  возможно обособление обстоятельства для придания ему уточняющего значения.